# while loop runiong when false

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I am currently working on robot car with a raspberry pi zero w, with some distance sensors and it can be driven around with a app on your phone with the blue dot library for python

My goal is to make it so that the user can freely drive the robot with 4 buttons one for left, right, forward, backward, when you press the robot will go in the specified direction and once the user releases with button the robot will stop I have this figured out and working

Now I want to implement the distance sensors so when the robot is moving backward for example the back sensor will constantly be read and if it gets within 20com within an object the robot will stop. I have the code for this figured out

To do with I have a global variable that is a boolean and once the button is pressed to go backward it's set to true and then I have a while loop with two conditions 1: that `run` is set to `true` 2: that the back sensor reads more than 20 the robot will go backward and if it gets too close to something it stops as intended

```
from bluedot import BlueDot
from gpiozero import Robot, DistanceSensor
from time import sleep
import random


robot = Robot(left=(20,21), right=(12,16))

# setup the distance sensor using GPIOZERO (DistanceSensor)

back_sensor = DistanceSensor(echo=25, trigger=8)
    global run

    def backward():
        global run
        run = True
        while run and back_sensor.distance * 100 >= 20:
            robot.backward()
        robot.stop()
```

Now when the backward button is released it runs a function called `stop`  that sets the global variable to false and stops the robot the only problem I am having once the button is released the function does not run until the loop from the function above is not true

```
def stop():
    robot.stop()
    print("stopped")

    global run
    run = False
```

code for the buttons

```
bd[1,2].when_pressed = backward
bd[1,2].when_released = stop
```

This problem is being caused because the while loop is being ran when the button is released so the stop function is never being ran making the run variable not set to false stopping the loop

If you have any suggestions on how i could fix this problem thank you in advanced

Comment: Why are you calling the functions within their definitions?

Comment: I am not, I am using the GPIOZERO library to control the movement of the motors

Comment: @MisplacedSoutherner - looks like `robot.backward()` and `robot.stop()` are methods of the `Robot` class: they're not the same as the `backward()` and `stop()` functions defined in OP's code.

Comment: `robot.stop()` (last line in function `backward`) is not calling your function `stop`, but a method `stop` defined in the class `Robot`. It's a lot tidier not to call your functions with the same name as other functions defined in other namespaces.

Comment: I don't know this library, so a tentative suggestion.  What about `bd[1,2].set_when_released(stop, background=True)` ?  From the docstring (https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/bluedot/dot.html?highlight=set_when_released#) that looks like it would run `stop` in a separate thread, so that `run` gets set to False without waiting for `backward()` to terminate.  Your problem at the moment is likely single-threadedness: `stop` can't execute until `backward` has completed.

Comment: yes I know thats why the loop is not stopping do you know of any ways that I could fix it?

Comment: Instead of `bd[1,2].when_released = stop`, how about `bd[1,2].set_when_released(stop, background=True)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* (don't have this code/hardware can't confirm) the problem is that "backward" and "stop" are like sending messages to the robot.  One function is sending the "backup" message over and over in a tight loop and the other function sends "stop".  If a "stop" message comes through and then a "backup" message your robot will just keep backing up.  In other words - "backup" means start backing up and keep doing it.  "Stop" comes through, and your robot stops backing up, but an instant later your robot gets hit by your endless flood of "backup" messages and resumes backing up.

Something simple to try and confirm this line of thinking would be changing your code to:

```
from bluedot import BlueDot
from gpiozero import Robot, DistanceSensor
from time import sleep
import random


robot = Robot(left=(20,21), right=(12,16))
bd[1,2].when_pressed = robot.backward
bd[1,2].when_released = robot.stop
```

If my understanding is correct the result of this will be that pressing the backward button will start your robot backing up.  Pressing the stop button will stop it.  From there it is a little refactoring to recover your desired behavior of including the Distance sensor.